# Flux.repeat() is not repeating

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm trying to repeat a subscribtion on a Flux like this:

```
    DirectProcessor<String> stringDirectProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();

    stringDirectProcessor
            .repeat(3)
            .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item));

    stringDirectProcessor.onNext("one");
    stringDirectProcessor.onNext("two");
    stringDirectProcessor.onNext("three");
    stringDirectProcessor.onComplete();
```

My expectation would be to see this output:

```
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
```

But I only get

```
one
two
three
```

However if I use `Flux.just()` instead of `DirectProcessor` I do get the expected output.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the expected behavior of the `DirectProcessor`**. I just read through the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors) and found the following regarding the `DirectProcessor`:

> Once the Processor has terminated (usually through its sink’s error(Throwable) or complete() methods being called), it lets more subscribers subscribe but replays the termination signal to them immediately.

So, since, `repeat` simply resubscribes, the `onComplete` handler will be called on them immediately. Are you sure you need the `DirectProcessor`?

EDIT: This behavior is also documented [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html)

> Note: If there are no Subscribers, upstream items are dropped and only the terminal events are retained. A terminated DirectProcessor will emit the terminal signal to late subscribers.